# App crashes on start

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi I was doing some testing earlier and my app was running just fine. I wanted to do some more testing so I decided to remove the app from my device and then reinstall it by running.

Well now for some reason I get to the stage where my splash screen shows up and then it crashes and I get the error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

This obviously means theres an array out of bounds correct? But why now and how can I found out where and what view controller this is happening on?  How could it run before and now all of a sudden when I try reinstalling the app through running it again I get this error?

Thanks

**EDIT**
The error is with the array in the following code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

  exploreViewController *view1 = [[exploreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"exploreViewController" bundle:nil];
view1.title= @"Explore";

Upcoming *view2 = [[Upcoming alloc] initWithNibName:@"Upcoming" bundle:nil];
view2.title = @"Upcoming";

calcViewController *view3 = [[calcViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"calcViewController" bundle:nil];
view3.title = @"Calc";

UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2];
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view3];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nil];
self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] init] autorelease];

NSArray *tabBarItems = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items; 
UIImage *tab1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"85-trophy.png"]; 
UIImage *tab2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12-eye.png"]; 
UIImage *tab3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"237-key.png"];

NSArray *tabBarImages = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tab1, tab2, tab3,nil]autorelease]; 
NSInteger tabBarItemCounter; 
for (tabBarItemCounter = 0; tabBarItemCounter < [tabBarItems count]; tabBarItemCounter++) 
{ 
    tabBarItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:tabBarItemCounter]; 
    tabBarItem.image = [tabBarImages objectAtIndex:tabBarItemCounter]; 
}
```

Comment: Show the code for nsarray and related loop.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Way to much code to post... big app. Is there someway through Xcode to debug where this is happening? Thanks

Comment: @Sarah For what View Controller? I have a lot of files. Or is this happening in the delegate? Thanks

Comment: You can add breakpoints and get the portion of code where the app is crashing. Also show the code for NSArray where the app is crashing.

Comment: [Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint when exceptions are raised.](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/) Xcode will show you exactly where the exception happens. We cannot possibly guess based on the information you've given us.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Code updated and posted... Found the error is in that array but can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: @Sarah Code updated and posted... Found the error is in that array but can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: @KurtRevis Code updated and posted... Found the error is in that array but can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Use the debugger. Look at `tabBarItems` and `tabBarImages`. Is either one nil? Do they have the same number of objects? Do they have the number of objects you expect? Why might that be the case?

Comment: I can't till if their nill but the crash is where tabBarItem=... Im just confused since I did not touch this code at all and it worked perfectly before I reinstalled it

Comment: Can you give number of objects saved in tabBarItems ?

Comment: Use NSLog(@"%@",tabBarItems) after the line NSArray *tabBarItems = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items;

Comment: @Sarah Thanks for the reply Sarah but it crashes before I can even NSLog that. I read somewhere that for some reason sometimes ios5 does not like that type of for loop and that a "for each" (I believe thats what it is called) makes it not crash. Do you know how to implement this type of for loop in my situation? Thanks in advance

Comment: "sometimes ios5 does not like that type of for loop"? No, that's nonsense. And earlier you said the exception was raised on the line `tabBarItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:tabBarItemCounter]` -- the suggestion was to add an NSLog *before* that part. Or, in the debugger console, "po tabBarItems" would also show you the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason for this crash is the following:
You are adding five items to your tabBar (nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4, nav6), but you only have three images for your tabs (tab1, tab2, tab3). So when the for loop reaches the fourth tab it crashes because `tabBarImages` only contains three objects.

Apart from that your code looks a bit messy - which could be the reason for not seeing the error on first sight.

**// edit**

You are complicating things - just try the following piece of code

```
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:__your_viewController__];
nav1.title = @"Explore";
nav1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"85-trophy.png"];

UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:__your_viewController__];
nav2.title = @"Upcoming";
nav2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12-eye.png"];

UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:__your_viewController__];
nav3.title = @"Calc";
nav3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"237-key.png"];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];    
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nav3, nil]];

[nav1 release];
[nav2 release];
[nav3 release];
```

Comment: Sorry I had posted old code, I made that change and I still get there error. I read somewhere that for some strange reason sometimes ios5 does not like the for loop and that using something like a for each loop (I think thats what it is called) works instead. Do you know how this is done? Thanks

Comment: Solved the issue and much cleaner code.  Thanks for your help!